# how to configure rampart TokenStorage in wso2esb 4.8.0

Tags: storage, token, rampart, wso2-esb

is it possible to configure the rapart tokn storage in wso2esb 4.8.0?

use case is this: 
I have a SAML secured proxy, when the proxy is called, rampart stores the saml token in the token storage: SimpleTokenStore, (implementation of org.apache.rahas.TokenStorage).

It saves all the tokens in memory, so this becomes very heavy in a production environment.

My solution is to write an implementation of that interface, but my question is: where should I configure it?

thank you

Lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

in the ws security policy file of the proxy service add in the **<RampartConfig>** element the child **<tokenStoreClass>my.company.TokenStorageImplementation</tokenStoreClass>**

then create a class that implements **org.apache.rahas.TokenStorage**, with custom business logic and put it in the carbon classpath eg: *repository/components/lib*

I think this is very usefull, because otherwise rampart save all received token in heap memory, so in a production environment this may cause Heap space saturation

hope it helps!